# Best database for 3d Points

Tags: database, 3d, space, points

I would like to build a database to store 3D coordinates (x,y,z) as long as some sata associated with each point. Which DBMS will be suitable for such a task?
Thank you in advance for your answer.

Comment: Do you mean, a data structure, or table structure for storing 3d points and associated data? IF so, what operations you are going to optimise this table for, like how will your search queries be?

Comment: yes. that is what I mean. I have no clear idea at this point what the queries will be...